# CompositeView slow to render items for large result set Marionette

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I'm currently working on a project that's using .NET MVC on the back end and Backbone (v1.1) with Marionette JS (v1.8.5) on the front end and I am experiencing some performance issues when trying to render a Composite view with 200 results or item views.

I first came across [this SO post of a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198924/backbone-marionette-composite-view-rendering) which helped me get a newer version of marionette (v1.8.5).

Handlebars templates are being used to show a html table with each itemView being wrapped in a tbody (this has a more complex accordion view within it hence tbody being used rather than a more semantic tr)

The Composite view is being initialised and shown in a Marionette region when it's sub app is initialised.

Here's a simplified version of my code.

**Activities sub app**

```
'use strict';

App.module('Activities', function(){
    this.startWithParent = false;
});

App.addRegions({
    RegionActivities: '#region-Activities' // <= this lives in .NET View of project
});

App.Activities.addInitializer(function (options) {

    var module = this,
        activities = new Collections.Activities();

    module.activitiesView = new Views.ActivitiesView({
        collection: activities
    });

    App.RegionActivities.show(module.activitiesView);

    activities.fetch();

});
```

**Activities Composite View**

```
'use strict';

Views.ActivitiesView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: Handlebars.templates['activities/activities'],

    itemView: Views.ActivityView,

    itemViewContainer: '.admin-table--activities', // <= html table that items are appended to

});
```

**Activities Item View**

```
'use strict';

Views.ActivityView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: Handlebars.templates['activities/activity'],

    tagName: 'tbody'

});
```

I read the [Marionette Docs on the better performing doc fragment](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-attachhtml)

So the performance issue that I'm having is that all 200 items are being appended one at a time and not utilising docFragment buffer. Through debugging I believe this is because the view is being instantiated with an empty Activities collection before the fetch, so Marionette thinks I'm updating the collection and sets the isBuffering to false.

I've also tried instatiating the activitiesView inside the fetch success callback like so;

```
activities.fetch({
    success: function(newCollection) {
        module.activitiesView = new Views.ActivitiesView({
            collection: newCollection
        });

        App.RegionActivities.show(module.activitiesView);
    }
});
```

This does append the 200 items to the collections elBuffer (takes about 4 seconds) but then takes another 50 seconds or so before anything is shown on screen. Debugging suggests the onShow method that's triggered by the collection could be causing this delay as it loop through each item one by one.

Have I missed something?

Am I doing everything in the right places?

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Seems strange to me that this could be so difficult.

Thanks for you time.
Tom

*Edit*

Here are both the composite view and item view templates.

**Activities CompositeView template**

```
<table class="admin-table admin-table--accordion admin-table--activities">

    <colgroup>
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="22%">
        <col width="23%">
        <col width="23%">
        <col width="22%">
    </colgroup>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Vessel</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Information</th>
            <th>Review Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

**Activity ItemView template** (each wrapped in tbody)

```
<tr class="table-title">
    <td>Col 1 data</td>
    <td>Col 2 data</td>
    <td>Col 3 data</td>
    <td>Col 4 data</td>
    <td Col 5 data</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-content">
    <td colspan="5">More info in here...</td>
</tr>
```

*Update*

**Results from chrome dev tools javascript CPU profile:**

Top 3 items all refer to Marionette triggerMethod taking up 80% of CPU.

[image: Dev tools CPU Profile Drilldown]

Full sized image at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjT3Z.png

Comment: Could you post the templates? This shouldn't make a difference, but try `activities.fetch().done(function() { App.RegionActivities.show(module.activitiesView); })`

Comment: Thanks @Meistro but that didn't help unfortunately. I'm now using the 2nd version from my question where I perform the fetch and then on success instantiate the view. Console.logging the activiesView instance happens in a 2nd. Problem seems to be around rendering the collection on screen. Mainly via region.show()

Comment: Can you post your `onShow` function? I don't see why calling that function a few hundred times should be causing you problems (50 sec delay). Your templates seem simple enough too. I have an app that very similarly inserts lists that are 200 items long and don't see the kind of perf issues you are running into. Something is missing from this equation.

Comment: Also, when you drill down into the `triggerMethod` portion of the profile what function are you getting to that is your own code?

Comment: @AndrewHubbs  I'm not using an onShow function in my composite or item views. I'll back to you regarding the devtools profile. I didn't notice anything relating to my own code from memory

Comment: @AndrewHubbs, checkout updated CPU profile image above.

Comment: So the good news is it looks like your problem is unrelated to using the buffer or DOM reflow issues. That trace indicates your issue is around AJAX requests. I don't see anything in your code that would cause an issue but are you making an AJAX request for each view? Have you overridden `Backbone.sync`? Do you have some kind of success handler on your `fetch` call making additional requests? If you don't know where this is getting called then I would recommend putting a break point at `jquery.js:8709` and walk up the stack trace until you see some of your own code.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks @AndrewHubbs.

1. So there are no ajax requests for views (that I know of).
2. There is a base collection and base model that both have their own custom sync functions - mainly for backbone basic auth. All other models and collections extend these.
3. No additional requests on the fetch success callback.

I will try the breakpoint you've suggested and see what I can find. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The buffer will be used when the collection is reset, so you could try

```
activities.fetch({reset: true});
```

The other option is to wait until the fetch is done (using deferreds/promises) before initializing and displaying your view.

Comment: Thanks @david-sulc but that hasn't worked. Yes it triggers the reset event on my composite view but the results still take about 1 minute to render on screen. I'll update the question with the drilled down cpu profile.